# How to restrict the user to double clicking on msi package

Tags: wix

My requirement: MSI package installation through silent mode only using power shell script. Here I am unable to restrict the user to launch MSI by double clicking on the MSI setup. What is Wix installer code need to be added for this.

Answer (score 0):

The typical technique is to define a secure custom public property such as SCRIPTDRIVEN and then write a Launch Condition that requires SCRIPTDRIVEN=1 or it aborts.  Then in your PowerShell pass SCRIPTDRIVEN=1.